# SparkSQL GroupBy with condition

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with Value ID and Value

```
| id | value    |
-----------------
|  1 |  UnKnown |
|  1 |     A    |
|  2 |  UnKnown |
|  2 |  UnKnown |
|  3 |     B    |
|  3 |     B    |
|  3 |     B    |
```

I need to select distinct id and corresponding value from the table. When selecting the Id should be unique and if it is having multiple values in the value field it should retrieve only not Unknown values

So the result should be like below.

```
| id | value    |    
-----------------
|  1 |     A    | 
|  2 |  UnKnown |
|  3 |     B    |
```

How do I achieve group by with condition like values are 'UnKnown' then keep 'UnKnown' else the value in SQL or Spark Scala ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample using Scala and Spark 2.0.0 SQL. You can try this on spark-shell.

```
val v = Seq((1,"Unknown"),(1,"A"),(2,"Unknown"),(2,"Unknown"),(3,"B"),(3,"B"),(3,"B")).toDF("id","value")
v.show
v.createOrReplaceTempView("v1")
spark.sql("select * from v1 where value!='Unknown' union (select * from v1 a where (select count (*) from v1 b where a.id=b.id and b.value!='Unknown')<1)").show
```